# Cannot open mysql-workbench

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-workbench

I am starting to work on mysql but cannot open mysql-workbench. When I try to open it via the command line of ubuntu, I get the following error:

> /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: symbol lookup error:
>   /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name

I looked up everywhere, but couldn't find a way to fix it!

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Usually Workbench's gdal lib is compiled without sqlite3 support. How did you compile Workbench and on what Ubuntu are you?

Answer (score 0):

Just install the latest deb from mysql-workbench website directly.