# mysql workbench is not running

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-18.04

I installed mysql-workbench by bellow command

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

I found two question on stack overflow but it did not solve the problem
[Cannot open mysql-workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55396652/cannot-open-mysql-workbench)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201645/mysql-workbench-cannot-open-symbol-lookup-error
https://askubuntu.com/questions/904972/mysql-workbench-fails-to-launch

all of the above answer suggest that i reinstall mysql-workbench which i did by bellow command

```
sudo apt purge mysql-workbench
sudo apt install mysql-workbench
```

but it did't work.
I reinstalled it multiple times but it still did nott work and give same error while running from command line

```
mysql-workbench
```

It produce error bellow
`/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name`

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled mysqlworkbench

```
sudo apt remove mysql-workbench
```

then i downloaded package from official website[hear](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/). After that i installed with bellow command

```
dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community_8.0.19-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
```

after that i run

```
mysql-workbench
```

although it is contrary to what other people suggest that install using apt or apt-get but that not worked and this thing worked for me

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Ubuntu You can find MySQL workbench on Ubuntu software (Ubuntu app store).

Comment: Please check this link , it might be helpful https://community.bitnami.com/t/undefined-symbol-sqlite3-column-table-name/71750